# Problem with Disk Warrior, repaired Timemachine backup won't copy

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have a corrupt Timemachine backup (.sparsebundle) diskutility is unable to repair.

Diskwarrior 5.2 (on Big Sur) was able to repair the image file and I was able to access the backups directory and see the files on the mounted preview disk.

However, I am having issues copying the files. I can copy the files from the disk in the finder.app but that takes forever for the image is 600+ GB.

In Diskwarrior itself copying the backups folder to another disk is not possible. It seems there is a permissions issue (foldericon). Pressing the copy button yields nothing. Its just dont doing anything.

I tried it also on a virtualbox (macos 10.13). There were no permission issues but when I try to copy the folder, it crashes.

Diskwarrior is able to restore my timemachine backup but I cannot copy the files. Did anyone have a similar problem and was able to solve it?

Comment: "I am having issues copying the files" using what? The Finder is about the only app that understands & can correctly 'unfold' TM backups - almost everything else will get lost in the links & try to copy 5TB.

Comment: Like I said, I can copy the files from the mounted preview disk in the finder.app. But I had to cancel the process because even after hours it was still just preparing to copy. There is a built in (in diskwarrior) window for copying the content of the preview disk to another disk, not folder. However, there seems to be some kind of permission issue (icon of the folder and copy process won't start) when I do that in big sur. In 10.13 there is no permission issue but the app crashes upon pressing copy

Comment: I wasn't aware you could copy from DW or the preview itself. If it can find everything & says it can fix it, I've always just let if fix it.

Comment: unfortunately DW says I cannot fix the image and have to copy its content.

Comment: Ah. That puts an entirely different perspective on it. That will also mean it's going to struggle figuring out the soft links & you're going to end up with a hundred copies of everything, i'd guess. I'd either just bin it & start afresh, or grab the biggest external drive you've got & see how far it gets doing a copy back, depending on how valuable the contents are. A late thought - I wonder if it would fare better running on an OS that still uses HFS+ for Time Machine.